# Excel ADO force data type

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I have data stored in excel files and I'm trying to run SQL queries on them using VBA.
Problem is that the data I'm working with is pretty dirty and unfortunately my control over its contents is very limited. Because of that excel is freaking out and is constantly assigning wrong data type to columns.

My best guess was that the type is determined by value inside first row o the table. But unfortunately the behavior is really unpredictable and it is not always the case. Here is the example:

[image]

I have columns with strings and empty values, zeros or errors. This columns are treated as double instead of text. And because of that every non number value in this column is erased after executing `CopyFromRecordset`. 
I also have columns with numbers and occasional empty values, and then the column is treated as text.

It is messing with SQL queries with `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses. Because if I'm making string comparison on column with a type double it won't work. Same if it happens in reverse if I'm trying to make number comparison on string column.

Sometimes problem can be avoided by setting proper formatting on problematic columns, sometimes by writing something else in the first row. But as I said it is really unpredictable and sometimes it does not work.

Tried something like this (following [this type table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum?view=sql-server-ver15)):

```vb
dbRecordset.Fields(2).Type = 200
```

But I get `Operation is not allowed when the object is open`.

I also tried to make manual conversion inside SQL query, but I feel like it much slower and the syntax is really messy. For example here is asserting type double (and it is only one column, I have couple dozen more):

```
Cdbl(IIf(IsNull(c.[Column4]), 0, c.[Column4])) > 0
```

So - is there a way to tell excel what type of data is inside each column? OR how to avoid my problems?

Here is my code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunCopy()
    Dim dbConnection  As Object
    Dim dbRecordset   As Object
    Dim strSQL        As String
    Dim dbField       As Variant
    Dim fieldCounter  As Long

    Dim src_wks As Worksheet
    Dim dst_wks As Worksheet

    Set src_wks = Worksheets("Src")
    Set dst_wks = Worksheets("Dst")

    Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set dbRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION WITH EXCEL ODBC DRIVER
    dbConnection.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                          & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"

    ' OPEN RECORDSET
    dst_wks.UsedRange.Clear
    dbRecordset.Open "SELECT d.* FROM [Src$] d WHERE d.[Column4] > 0", dbConnection
    dbRecordset.Fields(2).Type = 200
    With dst_wks
        ' HEADERS
        fieldCounter = 0
        For Each dbField In dbRecordset.Fields
            fieldCounter = fieldCounter + 1
            .Cells(1, fieldCounter).Value = dbField.name
        Next dbField
        ' DATA ROWS
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset dbRecordset
    End With
    dbRecordset.Close

    dbConnection.Close
    Set dbRecordset = Nothing: Set dbConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use another driver to access the data

```
    dbConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
```

From [connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/)

> To always use IMEX=1 is a safer way to retrieve data for mixed data
>   columns. Consider the scenario that one Excel file might work fine
>   cause that file's data causes the driver to guess one data type while
>   another file, containing other data, causes the driver to guess
>   another data type. This can cause your app to crash.

**Update:** I am still not sure what is needed. I attached code which uses an [in memory recordset](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3846361/Create-In-Memory-ADO-Recordsets.htm). The conversion is then done via copying data into this recordset. This might fail if column4 contains non integer values

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunCopy()
    Dim dbConnection  As Object
    Dim dbRecordset   As Object
    Dim strSQL        As String
    Dim dbField       As Variant
    Dim fieldCounter  As Long

    Dim src_wks As Worksheet
    Dim dst_wks As Worksheet

    Set src_wks = Worksheets("Src")
    Set dst_wks = Worksheets("Dst")

    Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set dbRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' Add a reference Microsoft ActiveXData Objects
    Dim rstInMem As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rstInMem = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With rstInMem
        .Fields.Append "Column1", adVarChar, 20, adFldMayBeNull
        .Fields.Append "Column2", adVarChar, 20, adFldMayBeNull
        .Fields.Append "Column3", adVarChar, 20, adFldMayBeNull
        .Fields.Append "Column4", adInteger
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockPessimistic
        .Open
    End With


    ' CONNECTION WITH EXCEL ACE DRIVER
        dbConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
    ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"


    ' OPEN RECORDSET
    dst_wks.UsedRange.Clear
    'dbRecordset.Open "SELECT d.* FROM [Src$] d WHERE d.[Column1] > 0", dbConnection

    dbRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM [Src$]", dbConnection
    'dbRecordset.Fields(2).Type = 200

    Do Until dbRecordset.EOF
        rstInMem.AddNew
        rstInMem.Fields(0) = dbRecordset.Fields(0)
        rstInMem.Fields(1) = dbRecordset.Fields(1)
        rstInMem.Fields(2) = dbRecordset.Fields(2)
        ' this might fail if dbRecordset.Fields(3) is a string
        rstInMem.Fields(3) = dbRecordset.Fields(3)
        rstInMem.Update
        dbRecordset.movenext
    Loop


    With dst_wks
        ' HEADERS
        fieldCounter = 0

        For Each dbField In rstInMem.Fields
            fieldCounter = fieldCounter + 1
            .Cells(1, fieldCounter).Value = dbField.Name
        Next dbField

        rstInMem.MoveFirst
        rstInMem.Filter = rstInMem.Fields(3).Name & ">0"
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rstInMem 'dbRecordset
    End With
    dbRecordset.Close
    rstInMem.Close

    dbConnection.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: This sadly won't work because I also have columns with actual numbers and they need to be correctly recognized. Whit this connection string number comparison do not work.

Comment: So you would like to tell Excel which data type each column is, right? BTW, your example ls a bit misleading because column1 only contains sth like _string1, string2, ..._ but you select `d.[Column1] > 0`. I think this cannot work. But if colum1n only contains numbers my connection string works with your code.

Comment: Or are you saying that column1 can contain both text and numbers?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I put `Column1` without much thought just as an example. And image was only demonstration how each column is recognized, not as actual output of presenter `WHERE` clause. Actual code would point at column with numbers. Give me a moment I will try to clarify my post.

Comment: I updated the answer but I am not sure if that's it what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add something like this towards the beginning of your code?

```
Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
```

Does that work for you?